# Creating showcase ISO / Live CD

Tags: virtualbox, live-cd, custom-distributions

So, I'm trying to create a showcase ISO for a specific project, so it can be demonstrated easily anywhere. Ubuntu is not a requirement, but the distro I'm familiar with (kind of).

What I need is: Java Runtime Environment 6.0, Postgres 8.4 with custom database installed, JBoss Application Server 4.2.1 with already deployed application and Firefox with handy bookmarks. Language pack for local language is desirable.

There is a [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) on Ubuntu Help section, but I'm a novice Linux user, that's too complicated for me right now. My guess of the easiest way possible would be to set an Ubuntu installation just like I need it inside VirtualBox (already done) and somehow turn it into a LiveCD.

Googling around I found [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com), but I couldn't get it right, the forums were quite slow, and the [few help](http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=1636.0) I got didn't fix my issues. Plus, it was recently discontinued.

Of the different problems I found, the most tricky is Postgres. It requires a special user that is the owner of the data folder, and such user is lost when creating an ISO with remastersys, making the database unusable. JBoss requires virtually no config at all.

Right now I'd like to know of any other tool or novice-friendly method to produce this Live CD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide to using relinux, the fork of remastersys
http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/

Comment: I've tested it and it works

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, the Postgres situation is still an open bug in relinux, as the owner says.

Comment: I'm testing a theory, I'll get back to you with something hopefully.

Comment: Ok then.  About your custom bookmarks etc, that's easy enough I already know you just copy your home folder configs to /etc/skel/.  egarding postgres, you can create the user everytime you bootup by adding the useradd command to /etc/rc.local.  'useradd -M -r postgres'  I have tested this, and the user is made and the postgresql folder still belongs to postgres.